# Cache all last distinct values

Tags: design-patterns, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a stream of different values with key (which I can group by key - character here):

XY - where X is a key and Y is some other data

** - reference point (see latter)

```
streamInput: -A1--B1----C1--A2-**-A3-A4--B2--->
```

What I want is some combination of [Flux.cache()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache--) and [Flux.distinct(keySelector)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct-java.util.function.Function-) let call this wanted method/pattern **cacheDistinct()**.

So when new stream will subscribe at reference point `**` I will get all distinct values before `**` and all new.

For example:

```
var cachedStream = streamInput.cacheDistinct();

//will print: -A1--B1----C1--A2--A3-A4--B2--->
cacheDistinct.subscribe(i -> print(i)) 

//user/event click and we open new subscription at reference time **

//will print: -B1-C1-A2--> (all last distinct before ** and all new) ---A3-A4--B2--->
//order before ** doesn't matter
cacheDistinct.subscribe(i -> print(i))
```

How to achieve this **cacheDistinct()** method/pattern?

PS. I use [project react](https://projectreactor.io/), but I need an idea here, so you can show how you do it in other languages/frameworks reactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I'll leave it here for next seekers (code uses project react v3.4, but I thing in other languages/frameworks it should be similar).

Basically, we have to cache grouped cached stream:

```
    Flux<String> streamInput = Flux.just("A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B2")
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .groupBy(i -> i.charAt(0))     //we group by our id
            .map(i -> i.cache(1))          //we cache last element in each group
            .cache()                       //we cache all grouped streams
            .flatMap(i -> i);              //we unpack streams to single stream

    //TEST bellow


    streamInput
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) //prevent blocking main thread
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("i1 = " + i));

    Thread.sleep(5000); //simulate user event to open stream at reference time **

    streamInput
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("i2 = " + i));

    Thread.sleep(100000);  //UGLY waiting for async code to be finished
```